# calculate everyone's spending for the last 3 days in a month period in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

python newbies here.I am trying to calculate everyone's spending for the last 3 days for a month period. the input will be:

```
date   name   amount
mar.5  mary    1
mar.6  mary    2
mar.6  mary    3
mar.7  tom     4
mar.8  mary    5
mar.8  tom     6
```

and the ideal result would be

```
date   name   amount
mar.5  mary    1
mar.5  tom     0    
mar.6  mary    6
mar.6  tom     0
mar.7  mary    6
mar.7  tom     4
mar.8  mary    10(2+3+5)
mar.8  tom     10(4+6)
```

etc.

I am trying to use python to create a loop to circle one the "last 3 days" but having trouble to identify a way to do this, any input will be appreciated. Hope everyone is safe under this virus thing.

Comment: bow you calculate this spending?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with [`DataFrame.rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) and `sum`, then reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), change levels by [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) and last sorting dates:

```
df = (df.pivot_table(index='date',columns='name', values='amount', aggfunc='sum')
       .rolling(3, min_periods=1)
       .sum()
       .fillna(0)
       .unstack()
       .swaplevel(0,1)
       .sort_index(level=0)
       .reset_index(name='amount')
       )
print (df)
    date  name  amount
0  mar.5  mary     1.0
1  mar.5   tom     0.0
2  mar.6  mary     6.0
3  mar.6   tom     0.0
4  mar.7  mary     6.0
5  mar.7   tom     4.0
6  mar.8  mary    10.0
7  mar.8   tom    10.0
```